# Question about notation in Banach spaces problem

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, and that $T_X : X \to Y^*$ and
>   $T_Y : Y \to X^*$ are both isometric isomorphisms. Show that if $(T_X x, y) = (x, T_Y y)$ for all $x \in X, y \in Y$, then $X$ is reflexive.

I don't understand the bracket notation used here. Is $(T_X x,y)$ supposed to mean the image of $y$ under the map $T_X x$? If so I don't understand why the second bracket has them the 'wrong way round'. Clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Another way to write it it to keep it straight in your head is $\langle T_Xx,y\rangle_{Y^*,Y} $ and $\langle x , T_Yy \rangle_{X,X^*}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bracket notation $(x^*,x)$ for $x\in X$, $x^*\in X^*$ is typically used to denote evaluation of $x^*$ at $x$, i.e., $(x^*,x)=x^*(x)$.

As for your misunderstanding, it could be a typo, and supposed to be $(T_X x, y) = (T_Yy, x)$, or the author may be freely changing coordinates in the parentheses.  If the second case is true, I would say that this is sloppy, but it (sort of) reflects the symmetry of the operators $T_X$ and $T_Y$.

In any case, the author is trying to say that $(T_Xx)(y)=(T_Yy)(x)$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$T_X(x)$ is an element of $Y^*$ and $(T_Xx,y)=T_X(x)(y)$